# jQuery getting value of selected radio option

Tags: jquery

I have a form with several fields, and I use the following to get the value of the fields

```
$("input[name='numbers']").val()
```

However this doesn't work for radio options, it just comes back with `undefined`. How should I get the value of a selected radio option?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="test" value="1" /><input type="radio" name="test" value="2" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [:input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) can be used to input elements.

Comment: That's not the problem. The `input` element selector will select radio buttons.

Comment: adding : before input helped! Thanks